# Apache/PHP multiple request handling and scheduling?

Tags: php, linux, apache, networking, node.js

```
User1<===HTTP====>Web Server
User2<===HTTP====>Web Server

Time~0, User1 connects to Web Server
Time~0, User2 connects to Web server

Time=10 seconds, User1 queries that further causes database search/update for  
                 10seconds.
Time=11 seconds, User2 is requesting something from server.

Will User2's request will be processed after Time=10+10=20 seconds?
```

I believe if PHP process is busy for 10 seconds, it can't handle others request.

Can someone please comment with respect to :

-Apache web server

-PHP process

-CPU process/thread scheduling

I am not very much clear about PHP, but i am pretty sure that Node.js can process others request if DB query or anything that is taking time( by using asynchronous callback).

Comment: Logs! Apache logs! Important! Consider including serving times in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Requests are independent and processed at the same time for both users, by using several processes/threads (by both Apache and PHP).

The only thing, in your scenario, that might delay one user in relation to another is if they're updating (or any other sort of change) the same content in a database, causing concurrency. Just selecting data from a database should also be processed at the same time for several requests.